# How to disable/strikeout previous date using AjaxToolkit CalenderExtender in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, toolkit

In my project, I have used `CalenderExtender` (which comes with AJAX Control Toolkit) in my webpages.

Now, I want my calender to strikeout or disable the previous dates.

How can I do it in `CalenderExtender`?

Comment: Look at the following Links: http://gratisaccount.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/disable-dates-in-calendarextender/ http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=149 TIP 6.

Comment: Thanks, I will let you know if I am able to disable the dates in Calenderextender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the js as follow to Strike Out the Past Days:

```
function checkDate(sender, args) {
            if (sender._selectedDate < new Date()) {
                alert("You cannot select a day earlier than today!");
                sender._selectedDate = new Date();
                // set the date back to the current date
                sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
            }
        }
```